# Collection of resource links is a good answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6799205/1783619 is nothing but a collection of links from what I can see. Granted, that's what the OP asked for; but does that really change the fact that it is a link-only answer?

I flagged it as "Not an answer", but got the following response: declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Perhaps it should have been flagged as "Low quality"? Did I just click the wrong radio button, or am I missing something bigger here?

I also notice my other flag on that question (on the other link-only answer) was marked as "helpful". The answer still exists (odd) and I would expect the flags to have been marked consistently.

Comment: @gnat: I deleted the question, which solves the whole problem.  If you're flagging link-only answers to such questions, you're looking at the wrong problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I generally prefer to focus on question but when the answer is particularly blatant, I'd rather risk an occasional flag decline (I also generally try to avoid even looking at such "answers", as I vote them down, lose rep and mods like you don't let flags to get through to delete crap and recover it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already closed, which solves the problem that caused the issue in the first place.  The answer is an answer, just not a great one.

When in doubt about which moderator flag should be used, cast a custom moderator flag.  The only reasonable action that a moderator can take on an answer is deletion, so explain in the custom moderator flag why you think the answer should be deleted.

Flags are declined when they have no merit.  Not an Answer flags on answers that clearly are answers are without merit.  Moderators are strict about these, because being lax confounds SE's automated software systems (especially review).

Unless it's something other than an answer, a downvote is usually more appropriate.  Also, note that the post you are referring to is very old, and the standards were somewhat different then.

Comment: It wasn't closed at the time (IIRC I was the first vote to close), so the flag seemed appropriate. For link-only answers is it recommended to use the custom flag? Was the discrepancy I saw in results just two different reviewers?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)** "Many resources here: <link1> <link2> <link3> <link3> <link5> <link6> <link7> <link8> <link9>"

Comment: What Gnat said.

Comment: Ah, so this falls under the "Crappy question asking for links, just close the question" heading. Understood. Thanks for the insight! I still would be interested in knowing which flag is correct for a general link-only answer though.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Unless you can thread the needle between "clearly not an answer," and "it's an answer, just a terrible one," use a custom flag, and explain in the flag description why you believe the answer should be removed from the site.